# ExpandableList getChildView running twice per child

Tags: android

I've got and `ExpandableList` which I assign to an extended `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. In here, I implement the `getChildView` method to setup and return a View for each child:

```
public View getChildView(int groupIndex, int childIndex, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LinearLayout layout;
    if (convertView == null) {
            layout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(MyApp.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rooms_room_list_row, parent, false);
        } else {
            layout = (LinearLayout) convertView; 
        }

    // Do some custom stuff with views on the layout
    ...

    return layout;

}
```

While debugging, I've noticed that `getChildView` is executed twice per child. All the values passed in (i.e, groupIndex, childIndex, isLastChild) are the same... so in group 3, if I've got two children, I'll see:

`groupIndex = 3`, `childIndex = 0`

then

`groupIndex = 3`, `childIndex = 1`

then it repeats:

`groupIndex = 3`, `childIndex = 0`

and finally:

`groupIndex = 3`, `childIndex = 1`

My view appears fine, i.e, there are only two children listed for the group, but why is it doing all the extra work?

**UPDATE & ANSWER**

It seems that if the the listview is set to a height of `wrap_content` then the `getChildView` will be called twice per child. Changing the height to `fill_parent` seems to fix this behavior.

Comment: can you show me your full adapter ? I have problems when using custom adapter for expandablelistview, getChild is never called.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I mentioned in your other question, the `ListView` calls `getView()` to get the dimensions (width and height) of *some* items first, *then* calls the `getView()` again to actually render the items. Check [this video out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70), it's "required reading" for Android. The bit that deals with your question is at minute 41:30.

Comment: Is there something I should be doing so that I'm not performing all the extra work to get the view ready?

Comment: THe video states that the height of the listview should be `fill_parent` instead of `wrap_content`. Try that (if that is the case).

Comment: Awesome. Do check that video out, it will go through 95% of the head-banging you will have when dealing with `ListView`s.

Comment: I spent so much time for fixing the similar issue, and this answer saved my time! +1!