# Why does Wrap_Content fire BindView more than once

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an Android app with a listView and am in the process of optimizing it.  It uses a custom cursor adapter in one activity and I noticed that bindview() was firing twice for each row of the list. While researching the BindView() and NewView() methods here, I read in a post that having Wrap_Content for the width of my listview was a bad idea.  I switched it to Fill_Parent and viola now bindview() and newview() each only fire once for each item.

So that I can better understand the internals of the Andorid OS, I would like to know why Wrap_Content caused bindview() to fire multiple times.

I have done several searches on Google, the android developer docs and here with no luck.

Any response is really appreciated.

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I recall correctly from a video from Google I/O, setting the width (or height) of a `ListView` to `wrap_content` will cause it to measure the first 3 items and base its dimensions off of those.  In order to measure those first 3 items, it must call `bindView()` to populate them.  Once it has measured, it will populate fully and call `bindView()` again on those first 3 and any subsequent.

This is due to the fact that the `ListView` only keeps in memory what is on the screen when you may have potentially an infinite number of items in the list.  It is not designed to `wrap_content` to your largest item because it could be stuck in the drawing phase forever.

Comment: Correct, I answered a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557240/expandablelist-getchildview-running-twice-per-child/6557284#6557284) yesterday. The video/time is provided there.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. ListView will occasionally call your adapter's getView for measurement purposes. There are no guarantees that the result of any call to getView will be placed on screen, or that the most recent call to getView is at all relevant to what is currently being displayed.