# Incorrect Image shown in ListView using custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, image, listview, download, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView populated using a custom ArrayAdapter. Each view item contains several TextView's and an ImageView. The ImageView is set with an image downloaded from the net using a separate AsyncTask thread so I can display the ListView with TextView items first whilst the images appear as the thread downloads them. It works 9 times out of 10 however occasionaly the image displayed for a particular list item is incorrect. If I then scroll this item out of view and then back in view the image rendered is the correct one. Anyone come across this before ?

Thanks.

Comment: post your getView() method, may be then we can find the source of your problem.

Comment: Let me guess. You are re-using convertView in your getView() method. If that so, that is kind of classic behavior you are facing. My advice is to impose a little check before you set image to your imageview. 
 However, we may be able to help if you post more details of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your view is getting recycled many times and you have some concurrency issues. Minimize the calls to `getview()` by setting your list layout `width` and `height` to `fill_parent`, if needed wrap it in a relative layout acording to this post:
[Why does Wrap_Content fire BindView more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565500/why-does-wrap-content-fire-bindview-more-than-once)