# BaseExpandableListAdapter calls getgroupview() when I edit the data in a EditText

Tags: android

I'm working with ExpandableListView's in Android.

I have a dialog which inflates this view:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/comments_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editTextNewComment"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
</ExpandableListView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNewComment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButtonPostNewComment"
    android:ems="10"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

My BaseExpandableListAdapter looks like this for the getgroupview()-method:

```
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    Log.d("LIST", "getGroupView() groupPosition " + groupPosition + "  isExpanded " + isExpanded + " row " + row);

    if(row==null) {
        LayoutInflater infl = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = infl.inflate(R.layout.list_item_comment,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(row);
        holder.imbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Integer pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                //Do something
            }
        });
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    holder.imbutton.setTag(Integer.valueOf(groupPosition));
    holder.header.setText(""+ (groupPosition+1) + " - " + comments[groupPosition].getOwner());
            //.... etc - setting all the textviews accordingly

    return row;
}
```

To my problem:

when I write stuff in my edittext the getgroupview gets called all the time! This is a output from the log for just adding ONE letter in the edittext:

```
03-15 14:07:51.072: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 0  isExpanded false row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.080: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 1  isExpanded true row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.088: D/LIST(4176): getChildView()
03-15 14:07:51.096: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 0  isExpanded false row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.104: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 1  isExpanded true row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.111: D/LIST(4176): getChildView()
03-15 14:07:51.119: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 0  isExpanded false row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.119: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 1  isExpanded true row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.127: D/LIST(4176): getChildView()
03-15 14:07:51.135: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 0  isExpanded false row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.135: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 1  isExpanded true row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.143: D/LIST(4176): getChildView()
03-15 14:07:51.151: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 0  isExpanded false row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.151: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 1  isExpanded true row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.158: D/LIST(4176): getChildView()
03-15 14:07:51.205: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 0  isExpanded false row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.205: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 1  isExpanded true row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.213: D/LIST(4176): getChildView()
03-15 14:07:51.213: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 0  isExpanded false row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.213: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 1  isExpanded true row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.221: D/LIST(4176): getChildView()
03-15 14:07:51.221: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 0  isExpanded false row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.221: D/LIST(4176): getGroupView() groupPosition 1  isExpanded true row android.widget.RelativeLayout{41a17d98 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-15 14:07:51.229: D/LIST(4176): getChildView()
```

getGroupView() and getChildView() gets called MULTIPLE times for each letter entered. In the above example the listview apparently gets redrawn eight times (I have 2 group-views and one child-view in the list for that example.)

What am I missing? The listview shouldn't even need to be redrawn when I type stuff in my edittext. And even if it is being redrawn, why is there eight calls to the different getview-methods?

EDIT:
I see now that even when i collapse and/or expand the groupviews, there is PLENTY of calls to the getgroupview and getchildview-methods. Is this how it's supposed to be?

EDIT2:
Did some testing now with using the list with edittext in a normal activity, and it seems that the list doesn't get redrawn as frequently then. So the problem seems to be in the fact that I'm presenting this in a dialog. Cannot see why it even should need to be redrawn though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExpandableList getChildView running twice per child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557240/expandablelist-getchildview-running-twice-per-child)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can never tell when `getView` methods ( also true for `getGroupView`) will be called and how many times.

but I do see something that can make it call more than needed : in your layout, you set the `ExpandableListView` height to **wrap_content**. I don't think its a good thing :

you make him need to redraw its child to know its size it order to fit its content, whereas it shouldn't need to wrap its content since its a scrollable layout.

Try to set it to `0dip` instead, with a `layout_weight="1"` in order to leave space for your text view :

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/comments_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editTextNewComment"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

Comment: To remove the wrap_content seems to solve my problem. For some reason the listview dont want to redraw itself when i edit the edittext now. :) Thank you sir!

Comment: And also: wrap_content seems to be a really bad idea. But the reason why i used it is because i present the list in a dialog and i only want the dialog to be as big as it needs to be, which it isnt now. Have to look this over.

Comment: @Guian I love you so much! You have saved my week!

Comment: More intuitive is to change height to match_parent instead setting 0dp/weight="1"

Comment: In his case 'match_parent' would have hiden the EditText at the bottom. But yes it can be done too.